# Datatable empty table text align changes on other devices

Tags: html, css, datatables

I've been working with datatables for a short period of time and I have this problem: I changes the empty table text for a table like:

```
language: { emptyTable: "No Requests"}
```

On the computer is aligned to left but the same text viewed from a tablet or from a phone becomes center align. 
I've tried to add something like:

```
language: { emptyTable: "No Requests", sClass: 'emptyT' }
```

and my CSS class:

```
.emptyT {
    text-align:left;
}
```

But the text alignment for empty table remains the same (left on computer but center for tablet and phone).
Is there any way to make it remain aligned to left no matter the used device type?

Comment: If I make my table responsive, the tablet or phone user will not be able to view all the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

Add the following CSS rule:

```
table.dataTable td.dataTables_empty {
    text-align: left;    
}
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e7weo2jj/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Thanks Gyrocode.com! You give me the perfect answer as usual :)